# Making Chrome automatically open documents

Tags: google-chrome

When I download a spreadsheet (or word doc, PDF, etc) Chrome shows it on the bottom left. Then I need to click on it to open it.

Is there a setting I change to open it automatically upon download?

Answer (score 4):

Click the little arrow next to a downloaded file in the downloaded file bar, at the bottom of your screen, and click “Always open files of this type". 
This cannot be done for executable files to prevent damage from possible malicious files.

Make sure you have programs on your computer than can open the types of files you want to open automatically.